# Get documents which timestamp is greater than 24 hs

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

So, I'm trying to get just documents that are 24 hs old, I saved a timestamp value in my database as timestamp

```
data class Order(@ServerTimestamp val timestamp:Date? = null)
```

Now, when I query, I want to bring back the documents in which timestamp is greater than 24 hours but the query does not succeed, I have checked and created all queries at my console

```
suspend fun getIncompletedOrders(): Resource<List<Order>> {
        val reminderList = mutableListOf<Order>()
        val oneDay = Date().time + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
        val query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collection("orders")
            .whereEqualTo("uid",FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid)
            .whereIn("status", listOf(1,2,4,5,6))
            .whereGreaterThan("timestamp",oneDay)
            .get().await()
        for(document in query.documents){
            reminderList.add(document.toObject(Order::class.java)!!)
        }
        return Resource.Success(reminderList)
    }
```

as you can see here I get the current time, add 24 hours to it and check if the timestamp stored in Firebase is greater than that, but I'm not receiving any documents when I change the timestamp to a day before in Firestore, whats happening ?

[image]

Comment: Please show a screenshot of the documents you're expecting to match.  Note that you're not passing a Date to whereGreaterThan, so you will never match an actual timestamp field value.  A number will only compare against other numbers.  Also note that you're asking for documents whose timestamp is greater than one day in the future.

Comment: I will be adding now the photo @DougStevenson , thanks for your time

Comment: Thats the document, so, if I move that 11 of july to 10 of july with the code given it should return this document but insteaad it does not fetch it, I'm doing something wrong ?

Comment: Please read my entire comment.  You're passing a number, but the field is a timestamp.  They don't compare.

Comment: Can you please elaborate an answer to this problem ? Thanks, I have been searching before asking

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line is computing a long integer, which is the number of milliseconds since the unix epoch, 24 hours in the future:

```
val oneDay = Date().time + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
```

However, the timestamp field in your database is a Firestore timestamp type field.  Firestore does not compare integers with timestamps.  You can only compare timestamps with timestamps.  You can pass a Date or Timestamp object from the SDK for that comparison.  Try converting the number into a Date:

```
whereGreaterThan("timestamp", new Date(oneDay))
```

Also keep in mind that your Date represents a moment in time one day **in the future**, but your problem description says you want timestamps up to one day **in the past**.  You probably want to subtract one day instead of add one day in that case.

Comment: Thanks Doug for your time !